# Error message 'no label views point to this text field'

Tags: android

I've just been doing the tutorial on how to make a temperature converter, but the tutorial does not explain how to get rid of the  exclamation mark on my edit text input. The error is:

> No label views point to this text field with an android:labelFor="+id/@+id/editText1"attribute

The tutorial is http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html.

Comment: There is an easy tinymce-like editor to help posting code. Paste it, select it, and press the curly braces button.

Comment: There is no 'android:labelFor="+id/@+id/editText1"' in that tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Take another look at your [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) layout file. You want to have `@+id/editText1` as the id. When you reference it, you want to call:

```
EditText editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1)
```

Note that you don't need to write the `@+id/` when referencing, only when defining an attribute. Maybe that could be the problem.

Also, if you want to change the text, I have not read the tutorial, but it should be defined inside `strings.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your TextView in the layout xml:

```
android:labelFor="@+id/editText1"
```

I don't know why, but it works.

Comment: Sorry, EditText, not TextView

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to suppress the error using lint, I'll describe below how to figure out the name of the lint warning to suppress.

Full warning message to suppress:

> Missing `labelFor` attribute
>
> No label views point to this text field with an
>   android:labelFor="@+id/searchTextView" attribute
>
> Text fields should be labelled with a labelFor attribute, provided
>   your minSdkVersion is at least 17.
>
> If your view is labeled but by a label in a different layout which
>   includes this one, just suppress this warning from lint.

To suppress it, add the attribute `tools:ignore="LabelFor"` to the component declaration, for example:

```
       <EditText
            android:id="@+id/searchTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="62dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/clearTextButton"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:inputType="textLongMessage|textNoSuggestions"
            android:maxLines="1"
            tools:hint="Search STATICDCA" 
            tools:ignore="LabelFor" />
```

To determine that the value was `LabelFor`, I did as follows in Android Studio:

1. Open the .xml layout file containing the component
2. Go to menu option Analyze > Inspect Code
3. Go to the inspection results at the bottom of the screen
4. Drill all the way down into the warning
5. Click the warning
6. On the right side of the inspection results is a detail view, click the drop-down box labeled "Suppress" and choose "Suppress with @SupressLina (Java) or tools:ignore (XML) or lint.xml"
7. This automatically added `tools:ignore="LabelFor"` to my component definition in my xml file